# Show that for every $x\in R$, there is $\sin(x) = 0 \iff \exists k \in Z: x = k\pi.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Define $\pi$ as follows:
$$\pi \,:=\, 2\inf\{x\in R: x > 0,\;\cos(x) = 0\}.$$

> Show that for every $x\in R$, there is:
> $\quad\sin(x) = 0 \iff \exists k \in Z: x = k\pi.$

So I started with:
$$ \sin(x) = (1/2i)(e^{ix}- e^{-ix}) = 0$$
$$\iff$$
$$\dots$$
$$e^i - e^{-i} = 0.$$

But now I didn't really get much further. Any tips on how one would approach that?

Comment: How are you defining $\sin$?

Comment: Basically sin: C -> C, $sin(x) = (1/2i) * (exp(ix) - exp(-ix))$
Where  exp: C-> C, $$ exp(z) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n/n!  $$
Also we defined for   $$y \in R , exp(iy) = cos(y) + i*sin(y)$$ but I don't see how that is related

Comment: Don't... use another definition.. like $\sin(x)=\cos(x-\pi/2)$
And btw: who defines $\pi$ like that?

Comment: Haha @b00nheT thanks for the tip, but thats not the idea. Since we assume that I don't know sin(x) = cos(x- pi/2)